# Laptop constantly draining its battery by turning on randomly

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, hibernate, asus-laptop

Occasionally I try to use my laptop when I've fully charged it the night before and unplugged it, then in the morning it is so dead that I get the BitLocker prompt for a key and my previous hibernation session is lost.

I've just tried to hibernate by pressing the power button (which is the configured action) but it is constantly turning itself back on within 1 second:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why is this happening? When I switch my laptop off it should stay off, not keep waking up. I don't want to fully shut down. It does this at random times, I just happen to have caught it doing it a few times on this occasion.

**More info:**

- ASUS FX504GD laptop
- Windows 10.1909.18363.1256
- No peripherals plugged in
- Wake-On-LAN is disabled on my NIC in Device Manager
- Wake Timers are disabled on Advanced Power Settings

Comment: (a) Turn your laptop OFF at night (not hibernate) and check. (b) Update BIOS and Power Management drivers from the ASUS Support Site.

Comment: Make sure "Wake On LAN" on your network card is disabled. It should be still the same on Windows 10 to configure it: https://superuser.com/a/1048446/62676

Comment: @Robert Good idea! Unfortunately Wake-On-LAN is already disabled in Device Manager on my NIC. The other NICs don't have a Power Management tab.

Comment: Then I would collect the tasks that cause your system to wake up e.g. via `powercfg lastwake` not sure if the even entries are reliable) and if it is a task open `taskschd.msc` and disable that it can wake-up the system. Note: You may have to repeat this after the next Windows upgrade.